# How to get the home directory in Lua (on GNU/Linux system)?

Tags: lua

How to get the home directory in Lua (on GNU/Linux system)?

It's the same thing that I get when I type `echo $HOME` in shell.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`os.getenv( "HOME" )` should be what you're looking for.

See the [docs](https://www.lua.org/pil/22.2.html).

Comment: Thank you a lot. I was searching how to dynamically adjust for a changing $HOME directory (when using lua files on different systems). By reading `home=os.getenv( "HOME" )` first and then `correct_path = home .. "/path/from/home"` I got it to work.